# Laravel scheduler run task on first monday of month

Tags: laravel, scheduler

I need to run command once a month on first Monday.

I had found one solution, but it does not work, this solution seems to be running every Monday and on first day of month. Tried looking into raw cronjob, so it seems that this is not possible to do with cronjob itself, and if Laravel scheduler is working on cronjob, then it is also not possible without some additional trigger mechanism.

```
$schedule->command('my:command')
        ->monthly()
        ->mondays()
        ->at('09:00');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve answered your own question: Laravel’s task scheduling is based on cron jobs, and you can’t do “first Monday” as a raw cron expression; only days of the month.

So if you *do* need to run it on the first Monday of the month only, maybe scheduled the task for every Monday but then put a guard as the first line of your command’s `handle` method:

```php
public function handle(): int
{
    if (! $this->isFirstMondayOfMonth()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Rest of command

    return 0;
}

protected function isFirstMondayOfMonth(): bool
{
    $firstOfMonth = now()->firstOfMonth(1);
    $today = today();

    return $firstOfMonth->is($today);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast replay. It was more of double checking if I understand on what scheduler is based.
Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark it as accepted if it answers your question.

Comment: This is incorrect, you can do first Monday of the month like so 0 30 8 * 1/1 MON#1

Comment: @dbinott You’re free to add your own answer if I have written something that is incorrect or can be improved upon.

Answer (score 3):

```
$schedule->command('foo')->mondays()->at("17:14")
            ->when(function () {
                return Carbon::parse('first monday of this month')->format("Y-m-d") == Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
            });
```